# Are we ever required to call removeTarget(_:action:for:) for UIControl objects before deallocation?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any situation where we must call `removeTarget(_:action:for:)` for `UIControl` objects before deallocation? Or is an added target automatically removed when its target object is deinit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d use that `remove` only if you want to change the `selector`. Otherwise you don’t need it. Upon deallocating the `UIControl` object, the reference to its target is no longer retained by it.

Comment: The target isn't removed from memory, it just isn't retained.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to call `removeTarget(...)`.

`addTarget(_:action:for:)` does not retain the `target`. So there is no reason for you to call it unless you want to.

You may call it in case you have multiple `UIControl.Event`s the control is configured to answer to.